# How delete/hide some component from backend menu in joomla?

Tags: joomla, components, hide, backend

I would like to hide some components in back-end in Joomla for some group of users. I think I should remove them from top-menu. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd ***highly*** recommend [noixACL](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control/7010).  It does a fantastic job of extending/managing the ACL of Joomla 1.5.  I'd suggest reading the installation and documentation thoroughly before rolling it out.  It took me a little bit of time to "wrap my mind around it", but it has been one of the most important additions to all the Joomla sites that we have.

Comment: I should add that the documentation can be confusing, but the end result makes the initial confusion well worth it - I can't imagine doing a J1.5 site without it now.